# Using Grep to create multiple variables in a loop per line - BASH

Tags: mysql, bash, loops, while-loop, grep

I'm trying to take a multiline file in the above format and make MySQL insert statement from it. End result aim is something similar to outputting: -

```
insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ("$ip", "$version")
```

per line for each of the following data examples (this is the input file, I want the IP address and the result of the msg segment - ie 4.0.3): -

```
ok: [192.168.0.214] => {s    "msg": "4.0.3"s}
ok: [192.168.0.210] => {s    "msg": "4.0.8"s}
ok: [192.168.0.208] => {s    "msg": "fdsajkghjfdka"s}
ok: [192.168.0.216] => {s    "msg": "Potatoes""""s}
```

The following greps get the IP's and message out appropriately: -

```
$ip=grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' 
$version= grep -oP '(?<=\"\: \").*(?=\"s})' #format of the message will vary going forward.
```

I want to put it in a loop, but I'm struggling. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: At least to me, it's not clear what part of this is the input format, and what part is the output format. I think it could use some editing to clarify what each looks like/needs to look like.

Comment: no need to bash loop, try `awk -v FS='[][]|"' '{print "insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ( "$2 " , "$6" )" }' yourInputFile`

Comment: PS that literally did it, thank you so much.

Comment: End result will be code vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. Don't do this.

Comment: @LetsScriptThis thanks for the edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, while-loop is not required. If your file is having the consistent structure like you provided in the question following command should print the required lines.

```
awk -v FS='[][]|"' '{print "insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ( \""$2 "\" , \""$6"\" )" }' yourInputFile
```

Note that above command will display the result in std out, if you want to execute then you can use `|bash` in the end of the command like:

```
awk -v FS='[][]|"' '{print "insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ( "$2 " , "$6" )" }' yourInputFile |bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, *MySql* `VALUES` syntax requires *complex* string arguments to be enclosed with quotes. 
To obtain valid MySql insert statements use the following approach:

```
awk '{ gsub(/[\[\]]/,"",$2); sub("\"+s}","\"",$6); 
       print "insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values (\""$2"\", "$6");" }' file
```

The output:

```
insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ("192.168.0.214", "4.0.3");
insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ("192.168.0.210", "4.0.8");
insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ("192.168.0.208", "fdsajkghjfdka");
insert into ansible_db (ip, version) values ("192.168.0.216", "Potatoes");
```

Comment: Thank you, I had already noted and escaped the quotes as per your example. I will request that PS updates his answer to include that though.